# c# button click event. Extracting the coordinates from a two dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, button, multidimensional-array

I am making the game minesweeper on c# and this part of my code is checking to see if the user pressed a certain button on the grid. However, the way to do that I believe it split the x y coordinates of the button he pressed.

Meaning the way the code works is that there are two 2-dimensional array going on here. There are 100 buttons button[10,10]. and behind that is a grid called grid[10,10] and on the grid I said -1 is a bomb and 1 is an empty space. I am trying to extract the x-y coordinate that he presses from the button and check the grid with it. And this is the code below:

However,when I press a button -  at code int x = System.Convert.ToInt32(split[0]); I get a  'System.FormatException'.

What am I doing wrong?

```
void bttnOnclick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        Button bttnClick = sender as Button;

        string[] split = bttnClick.Name.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });

        int x = System.Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);
        int y = System.Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);


        if (grid[x, y] == -1)
        {
            //Game Over!
            for (int xx = 0; xx < SizeX; xx++)
            {
                for (int yy = 0; yy < SizeY; yy++)
                {
                    if (grid[xx, yy] == -1)
                    {
                        buttons[xx, yy].Visible = false;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the name of the button? Does it contain two integers separated by a space?

Comment: no I instantiated it like this: Button[,] buttons = new Button[SizeX, SizeY];

Comment: What's the format of button name?

Comment: I just did this now: string s = bttnClick.Name = " ";

Comment: Never mind i figured out what you are saying I got it to work thanks!

Comment: Did you correct naming convention or saved the coordinates in tag?

Comment: You can only check one post as accepted answer, while you can vote for as many answers as you find helpful, including the accepted one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dynamically creating your buttons, make sure you are setting the name property.

```
Button[,] buttons = new Button[10, 10];

for (int i = 0; i < buttons.GetLength(0); i++ )
{
     for(int j = 0; j < buttons.GetLength(1); j++)
     {
          buttons[i, j] = new Button()
          {
               Name = i + " " + j
          };
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error massage is self describing and probably `split[0]` is a string that is not convertible to integer.

You can use either of this options to solve the problem:

- **Suitable Naming Convention**

  You can use a suitable naming convention.
- **Store Coordinates in a Point and put it in Tag**

  You can store coordinates in a `Point` structure in the `Tag` of buttons when you are adding them to the array using `button.Tag= new Point(x,y);` Then you can simply unbox the position using `point p= (Point)(((Button)sender).Tag);` and use `p.X`, `p.y` as index of array.
- **Use TableLayoutPanel and GetColumn and GetRow Methods**

  You can use a `TableLayoutPanel` and add your buttons to the panel. Then you can find coordinate of each clicked button using [`GetColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`GetRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getrow(v=vs.110).aspx) methods of `TableLayoutPanel` this way:

  `var column = tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumn((button)sender);`
  `var row = tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow((button)sender);`

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all:

> 'System.FormatException'

At the line - `int x = System.Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);`
You are trying to convert a string to an int.  However, the string that you trying to convert is in the wrong *format* and does not equate to a string.  Try debugging with `string splitString = System.Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);`.  Then see the value held in splitString. I am guessing it not  the value that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] split = bttnClick.Name.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
```

At first, I would like to state that the Name property for a control has some restrictions. I don't understand how does your code compile. Take a look at this [WPF Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name(v=vs.110).aspx). 
You might use the *tag* property and/or use underscore ( _ ) instead of space.

Regarding your question: the content of  *string[] split* has different content that you expect. Take a look at it with a debugger.